# Why different results when narrowing columns and fetching only first row?

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm running two queries in DB2

```
SELECT * from mrptable FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
--result for mrpcolumn = 1150131

SELECT mrpcolumn FROM mrptable FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
--result for mrpcolumn = 0
```

Why would these two results be different?

Comment: I think the use of the wildcard causes some strange cursor position behavior when using `fetch`. I recommend specifying all columns you would like returned. Have you tried comparing the following queries? 

SELECT m.mrpcolumn, m.* from mrptable m FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY \\
SELECT mrpcolumn FROM mrptable FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

Comment: @MylesBaker - While it's a good idea to always explicitly list the specific columns you're interested in, that's not what's causing the issues here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have no `order by` clause on either query, so the result set ordering is indeterminate.  You could even run the same query twice and get different results.

There are many reasons why the results sets would not be in the same order.  The most likely is that you have an index on `mrpcolumn`.  This index covers the second query, so the query could use the index to get one row.

The first would go to the datapages.

Another reason would be execution in a parallel environment, where is it indeterminate which thread/process returns the first value.

When using `fetch first` clauses, you should generally be using `order by`.